# How to solve date format exception in Okhttp?

Tags: android

When I tried to hit POST API with some parameter in postman, I'm getting 200
When I tried to hit POST API with some parameter using Retrofit, I'm getting 417

Exception: `Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "null"`

```
 `Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "null"`
```

Comment: why you use two hasmap just use one with differnt value and key and also show me your postman how you send the data

Comment: what is  date format in API?

Comment: @Amitpandey {
    "body": {
        "sex_id": null,
        "appointment_statudid": null,      "mpi": "",
        "appointmentfromdate": "2020/02/28",
        "appointmenttodate": "2020/02/28",
        "insuranceType": null
    }
}

Comment: @VishalBhut That I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Date` object not a `String`. And also in your Retrofit builder setup add `Gson` `converterFactory` with date pattern:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)

 gsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat(SERVER_DATE_PATTERN)
                .serializeNulls()
                .create())
```

and post it like this:

```
@POST("api.....")
Call<Response> validateRegistrationCredentials(@Body YourPostBodyModel body);

class YourPostBodyModel {
  Date bithday;
  ......
}
```

Comment: wait, do not go anywhere and let me try

Comment: You should see you post body in Android studio LogCat. Are you posting correctly? Using Body model? and @Post annotation?

Comment: yes I seen. it is going correctly. If I use JSONObject.NULL, it is not going in body and 417 says missing required propertydate_of_birth

Comment: so probably you just using wrong date format if that error comes from server not from retrofit

Comment: but how can I fix? see in postman, I'm passing null and I'm getting correct response

Comment: first you need to know your back end server date pattern. Then just follow all steps that I mentioned. See updated answer

Comment: That's not possible dear

Answer (score 0):

```
 @POST("your api site")
fun sendData(@QueryMap hashMap: Map<String, String>): Call<ApiResponse<Any>>
```

make a hasmap for this

```
Hashmap<String,String> hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    hashMap["sex_id"] = sexid
    etc
```

Comment: can you please do it in java/

Comment: but some values or interger and string

Comment: than use jsonobject and convert in into int and string and pass  it

Comment: means ? it is saying Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Comment: HashMap<String,Object> yourHash = new HashMap<String,Object>();
yourHash.put("message","message");
yourHash.put("timestamp",timestamp);
yourHash.put("count ",count);
yourHash.put("version ",version);

Comment: Exception: {"head":{"StatusValue":417,"StatusText":"Failed"},"body":{"Error":" must be object"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
String dtStart = "2020/02/28";  
Date date;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");  
try {  
    date = format.parse(dtStart);  
    System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Put Date Like This

data.put("date_of_birth", date);